# How to get total advertising costs filtered by a product in Sponsored Brands reports

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I would like to ask help in my current project that performs API calls from Amazon Advertising API reports using scripts run by cron jobs. https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/sponsored-brands/2/reports

The endpoint I need to call is the sponsored brands reports API, and the goal is to get the total advertising costs filtered by a product. Calling the API to get the total costs for all products is easy since all I need to do is to supply the date.But for total costs filtered by product, I don't see any helpful information on how to achieve it. For sponsored products and sponsored display Apis are really easy as well since I cna just pass the `sku` and `asin` in the `metrics` parameter.The product can then mapped from the `asin` and `sku` in the api call response.But in Sponsored Brands, it is not possible to pass the `sku` and  `asin` in an api call.It doesn't also included in the api response.

Does any one has solution to this ?

Regards

Comment: I think you uncovered a limitation of Amazon's advertising API. The documentation is not always accurate. For example,

It says you can request the metrics: targetingExpression and targetingText. While the request does not cause an error, it doesn't actually return any data. If it did, you could look for asin="xxx".

It also fails to mention that it does in fact allow you to make a request for "targets" like you would "keywords". Again, it doesn't error out, and does provide a download URL, but when you unpack this response- it is empty.

I do not have a solution yet.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow finally I got the solution.Yes you are right.And event the amazon support doesnt know the answer

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: @ira How did you resolve it? Please do share.